# Why won't iptables allow MySQL connections?

Tags: centos, mysql, iptables

For some reason mysql connections from a specific IP address aren't allowed. This is the rule I have (grabbed from `iptables-save`):

```
-A INPUT -s 12.34.56.78/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 22,80,3306 -j ACCEPT
```

What's interesting here is that SSH connections and HTTP pages load perfectly without issue. I added 3306 for MySQL connections later, but they seem to be ignored. Why?

I'm on CentOS. I have restarted iptables service and have the IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP/RESTART set to yes.

Running `netstat -tunelp` shows me this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27         8849593    10712/mysqld
```

Here is my full list of rules from `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            state NEW multiport dports ssh,http,mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  some-resolved-hostname-1.com  anywhere            state NEW multiport dports ssh,http,mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  some-resolved-hostname-2.com  anywhere            state NEW multiport dports ssh,http,mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  some-resolved-hostname-3.com  anywhere            state NEW multiport dports ssh,http,mysql
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Note:** There are no logs (including errors logs) on the server side. The error I get when trying to connect is:

```
D:\>mysql -u username -p -h 12.34.56.78
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '12.34.56.78' (10060)
```

Additionally (as this was from a Windows machine trying to connect) I tried this:

```
D:\>telnet 12.34.56.78 3306
Connecting To 12.34.56.78...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed
```

Also note that `skip_networking` is to to `off`.

Comment: Can you post all your rules?

Comment: Check with `nestat -tunelp` that MySQL isn't listening on `127.0.0.1` only, as it's the standard configuration (while SSH and Apache listen on **all** interfaces by default).

Comment: @zhenech I have listed all the rules
@MrShunz I think it's running on all IPs - I have added the line of output from `netstat`

Comment: What is the exact error messages tou get when trying to connect ? Are there any relevany messages in your logs ?

Comment: try using netcat to verify whether you can open a tcp connection to the port.
first connect locally nc -v localhost 3306 Connection to localhost 3306 port [tcp/vs-server] succeeded! and then try it remotely, just to verify that iptables is rejecting it.

Comment: I have added more details on the exact errors - should have added those earlier sorry Iain.

Comment: This is what I saw on the local machine: 
`[user@machine ~]$ nc -v localhost 3306`
`nc: connect to localhost port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`
`Connection to localhost 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!`
`N`, but the machine at the remote IP is Windows, but see my post update for a telnet connection attempt

Comment: Is your windows firewall configured to allow outbound connections to port 3306 ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Solution found now thanks to Bert's comments on his own answer. Will accept his answer once modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, have you changed `my.cnf` to configure MySQL to listen for connections on the server's IP address? Your  file should contain this line:

`bind-address = <public_ip_address_of_your_machine>`

Second, have you given permission to the user connecting from that IP address to connect, in MySQL?

`GRANT ALL ON example.* TO someuser@'12.34.56.78' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`

That would solve the issue if you are getting an error message similar to `"Access denied for user: 'someuser@12.34.56.78' (Using password: YES)"`

Last, make sure that your router has port-forwarding and firewall rules allowing incoming connections to the MySQL server.

Comment: As you can see, it's bound to `0.0.0.0`, which `accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address
As for the user, that is setup, however it's a timeout, not an actual MySQL error.

Comment: Is there another firewall or router connecting that machine to the Internet?

Comment: Yes! Router. Man alive I should have thought of that. Just had to setup port forwarding for the port on the router. Would you mind appending your answer, so I can mark it as correct, seeing as you triggered the thought process to make the fix please? :)

Answer (score -1):

I see --dports instead of --dport, maybe 22 and 80 works because they're allowed on another rule and it just can't apply this line?

Comment: This is valid syntax, with the multiport module. See here: http://howtonixnux.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/iptables-using-multiport.html